# Ensure responses are not cached

Tags: http, caching, cache-control, browser-cache

I have a particular HTTP response which I don't want cached because it has private/sensitive data in it

I'm already setting **Cache-Control** to **no-store**, 
 which should handle clients supporting HTTP/1.1.

How do I use the **Expires** header to do the same for HTTP/1.0? Should I just set it with an arbitrary timestamp from 1970 or something? Is there a special value to tell it never to cache?

Comment: You should explain *why* you don't want the response cached. No-store might not do what you're hoping, or it might be overkill.

Comment: @Eric: I don't want the response cached because it has private/sensitive data in it. I'll update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP RFC says:

> To mark a response as "already expired," an origin server sends an Expires date that is equal to the Date header value.

You should set the expires header to a date in the past. And you should also set the must-revalidate flag on the Cache-Control header.

**Expires:** Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
**Cache-control:** no-cache, must-revalidate

You can find a good article dealing with caching issues on the [doctype wiki](http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/ArticleHttpCaching):

> Setting an Expires header in the past ensures that HTTP/1.0 and
>   HTTP/1.1 proxies and browsers will not cache the content. The
>   Cache-control directive also tells HTTP/1.1 proxies not to cache the
>   content. Even if proxies may be configured to return stale content
>   when they should not, the must-revalidate re-affirms that they SHOULD
>   NOT do it.

Comment: Is must-revalidate necessary if I'm using no-store as opposed to no-cache?

Comment: If the reason the data should not be cached is security, then you have to add `no-store`. This prevents browsers and web caches storing any of the data in non-volatile memory. Without this flag browsers can still keep some of the data to use for functions like 'back' and 'view source'.